# Split multiple JSON string into strucutred table using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, etl

I am trying to split a data set with an ID and JSON string into a structured table.

The difficult part is I need it to be dynamic, the JSON string varies often and I want headings to be determined by the unique values in the input column at that time. I need the script to be able to create headings if the string changes without needed to recode the script.

We have about 150 different JSON strings we are hoping to use this script on, without recoding it for each one. Each string has lots of data points.

I have a script working but it splits them one by one, need to build something that will do bulk in one go, by looping through all outputs in B and creating a column for each unique field in all the strings, then populating them.

The script works if I paste the additional info straight in, however I am having trouble reading from the sheet

```
  var inputsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Input");
  var outputsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Current Output");

  var additionalinfo = inputsheet.getRange(1,1).getValue()
  Logger.log(additionalinfo)

  var rows = [],
      data;

    for (i = 0; i < additionalinfo.length; i++) {
        for (j in additionalinfo[i]) {   

          dataq = additionalinfo[i][j];

          Logger.log(dataq);

          rows.push([j, dataq]);
    }
      dataRange = outputsheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, 2);
      dataRange.setValues(rows);    
  }
}
```

Here is a link to the sample data. Note that in Sample 1 & 2 there are different headings, we need the script to identify this and create headings for both

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BMiVuAgDbibLw6yUG3IZ9iw4MZTaVVegkw_k3ItQ4mU/edit#gid=0

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I understood that I couldn't correctly understand your question because I couldn't understand your changed question, and also, my answer was not useful for your situation. In this case, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this again. I think that I have to study more and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script that produces dynamic headers based on the json that has been read. It collects all json data, get its keys, and remove the duplicates.

#### Script:

```
function JSON_SPLITTER() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var inputsheet = spreadsheet .getSheetByName("Input");
  var outputsheet = spreadsheet .getSheetByName("Current Output");
  var additionalinfo = inputsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var keys = [];

  // prepare the additionalInfo  data to be parsed for later
  var data = additionalinfo.slice(1).map(row => {
    // collect all keys in an array
    if (JSON.parse(row[1]).additionalInfo) {
      keys.push(Object.keys(JSON.parse(row[1]).additionalInfo));
      return JSON.parse(row[1]).additionalInfo;
    }
    else {
      keys.push(Object.keys(JSON.parse(row[1])));
      return JSON.parse(row[1]);
    }
  });
  
  // unique values of keys, modified to form header
  var headers = [...new Set(keys.flat())]
  // Add A1 as the header for the ids
  headers.unshift(additionalinfo[0][0]);
  // set A1 and keys as headers
  var output = [headers]

  // build output array
  additionalinfo.slice(1).forEach((row, index) => {
    var outputRow = [];
    headers.forEach(column => {
      if(column == 'Contract Oid')
        outputRow.push(row[0]);
      else
        outputRow.push(data[index][column]);
    });
    output.push(outputRow)
  });
  outputsheet.getRange(1, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Update:

- Modified script for no-`additionalInfo` key objects.

Comment: Thank you so much @AsyntuBu      This looks like it could work perfectly...
I'm just getting this error:


SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
(anonymous) @ Copy of Code.gs:11
JSON_SPLITTER1234 @ Copy of Code.gs:9

Comment: in your sheet sample, what sheet are you trying to process so I can replicate it on my end @SimonHardham

Comment: It is working now, thank you!
This answers my Q

Comment: Note that the logic for getting dynamic headers can be also applied to Tanaike's answer @SimonHardham. You might need to adjust it but it should work after some modification if needs be.

Comment: It works for my India data but not Singapore, I get this issue, any ideas why?
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
(anonymous) @ Copy of Code.gs:11
JSON_SPLITTER @ Copy of Code.gs:9

Comment: Checking @SimonHardham

Comment: @SimonHardham, include an additional row on your sample sheet that contains the row making it fail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243015/discussion-between-asyntubu-and-simon-hardham).

Comment: There are a few employees breaking it, this is one:  "{
  ""isComplianceUploaded"": true,
  ""isOpsOnboardingComplete"": true
}"

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry the chat cut out, I was testing the script and it works perfectly.

Comment: The only other modification which would be good is if we can look for the column which is headed "Data" and always split that.
I would like to be able to have 4 or 5 columns of meta data then have the payload in a column always called "Data".
It would be good to be able to keep the inputs from all columns to the left of the Data column in the output sheet.
I have done an example in the sample data 1 & 2.

Comment: can you help here by any chance? @ASyntuBU